# "Class" not found

Tags: php, class, laravel

Loaded the Natnanmac GUID generator from GitHub for Laravel in a 5.2 project.

I can call it from within a Blade view like:

```
<?php $myguid = GUID::generate(); ?>
{!! $myguid !!}<br />
```

and it generates a GUID just fine.  If I try to use it within a controller like:

```
public function generateGUID()
{
    $newguid = GUID::generate();
}
```

it throws a

```
FatalErrorException in MainController.php line 86:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\GUID' not found
```

I have a feeling it is a `use` clause I am missing, but have NO idea what.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `use Nathanmac\GUID;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is trying to find the class inside the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace. Try

```
public function generateGUID()
{
    $newguid = \GUID::generate();
}
```

Comment: That corrected the issue.  But why would it work without the leading '\' in the view but not the controller?

Comment: Because the view is not under any namespace so php looks for the class in the global namespace. The controller on the other hand is under a namespace if you want to use a class in the global namespace you have to be explicit about it. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php